# Routing to delete in my restful web service is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

I am having an problem routing to my delete method on my restful web service for permissions.
My routes are set up as follows :

```
  namespace :service do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :surveys do
          resources :permissions, only: [:index, :create, :delete, :update]
        end
      end
    end
```

The following spec passes

```
   it "routes toya expected controller method" do
      {:get => 'service/v1/surveys/3/permissions'}.should route_to(controller: 'service/v1/permissions', action: 'index', :survey_id => "3")
   end
```

This spec fails

```
describe 'DELETE :destroy' do
    it "routes to expected controller method" do
      {:delete => 'service/v1/surveys/3/permissions'}.should route_to(controller: 'service/v1/permissions', action: 'destroy', :survey_id => "3")
    end
  end
```

The snippet from my controller is as follows

```
module Service
  module V1
    class PermissionsController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => []

      def index
        render :json => permissions,  :each_serializer => Service::V1::PermissionSerializer
      end

 def destroy
            debugger
            # cant route to here 
            a = 1
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions ? I am slightly confused between destroy and delete, I think that might be the source of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass permission id as well like:-

```
{:delete => 'service/v1/surveys/3/permissions/permission_id'}.should route_to(controller: 'service/v1/permissions', action: 'destroy', :survey_id => "3", :id => "permission_id")
```

Comment: I assumed you would be able to not specify an id and send through an array of id's, a bit optimistic I guess